# slick 3 insert or update by custom field

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

According to the API http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/api/#slick.driver.JdbcActionComponent$SimpleInsertActionComposer

insertOrUpdate == Insert a single row if its primary key does not exist in the table, otherwise update the existing record.

Can I insertOrUpdate by custom field ?

I solved it by 2 queries

```
  def insertOrUpdate(name: String) = {
    Await.result(db.run(tableQ.filter(_.name === name).result), Duration.Inf).headOption match {
      case Some(t) => Unit
      case None => Await.result(db.run(tableQ += ...), Duration.Inf)
    }
  }
```

Can slick do this by insertOrUpdate ?